# Is the word "persons" grammatically correct?

Tags: word-usage

When I read a book, 'persons' was used in the sentence; however, I have known it is incorrect grammatically. Is it acceptable?

Comment: *Persons* is a legitimate English word. In many contexts it is ordinarily replaced by *people*, but we cannot tell you whether this is the case in a particular context unless you provide that context.

Answer (score 3):

[worldwidewords.org](http://www.worldwidewords.org/articles/people.htm) has an interesting explanation for the history and difference between people and persons as plurals of person. The salient point is:

> The normal plural of person was persons, as in “two persons were present”. However, there is evidence from Chaucer onwards that some writers chose to use people as a plural for person, not only in the generalised sense of “an uncountable or indistinct mass of individuals” but also in specific countable cases (Chaucer wrote of “a thousand people”). This began to be questioned in Victorian times, and the pseudo-rule grew up that the plural of person is persons when a specific, countable number of individuals is meant, but that people should be used when the number is large or indefinite.
>
> Modern style guides disagree, being able to quote many examples of the
>   use of people as the plural of person in both situations, for example
>   in sentences like “the plane crash killed 370 people”, and “Many
>   people visit the park every day”. Though persons survives, it does so
>   largely in formal or legal contexts (“Killed by person or persons
>   unknown”, “This taxi is licensed to hold four persons”) and often
>   seems awkward and old-fashioned. Where it survives it emphasises that
>   each member of a group is being considered as an individual: “The
>   nearest persons they can vent their feelings on are the ball boys and
>   girls”, “Eight persons shared a single room”. From the evidence, it
>   seems that the trend towards using people instead of persons is
>   accelerating and that it may not be so long before persons vanishes
>   from the language except in certain set phrases.